# How to set a session variable from the UserProvider object in Symfony2?

Tags: php, session, symfony, internationalization

In order to set the current UI language, I need to set the user default language to a session variable when the User information is being retrieved from the UserProvider object (loadUserByUsername method).

How can I access to session to set the current UI language from the UserProvider object?

Do you know a better way to manage the UI current language?

Comment: You should look at this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html

Comment: That sounds great, but how can I access that listener from the UserProvider object?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this data to the request in a request listener. and fetch it later on.

```
 /**
 * Set the right format  to notify FosRest Handle view regarding the real format that the request contain
 *
 * @param GetResponseEvent $event
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
 */
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $callback = $request->get('callback');


    if ( $callback!=''){
        $event->getRequest()->attributes->set('_format','jsonp');
    }


}
```

and in services.yml:

```
kernel.listener.callback_request:
        class: CallbackRequestListener
        arguments: []
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```